# How Do I Use Simple Form to Create A Checkbox (to Select Multiple Options) and Display Information as an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using Simple Form for my app and I would like to give users the ability to select multiple items and display it on their profile as a list.

The line in my form looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :subject, as: :check_boxes, collection: [ "Math", "English", "Science"] %>
```

This is how I am displaying it on the front:

```
<%= @tutor.subject %>
```

If someone were to click math and science I would want the like to appear: "Math, Science"

I am having trouble doing this as it seems like it's not recognizing the checkbox selections.
How would I build this step by step?

Answer (score 0):

The sane solution to the problem is to use two tables instead of just a string - one for the subjects and a join table between subjects and tutors. This decouples the data from your application code.

```
class Subject
  has_many :tutors
  has_many :subjects, through: :tutor_subjects 
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class TutorSubject
  belongs_to :tutor
  belongs_to :subject
end

class Tutor
  has_many :tutor_subjects 
  has_many :subjects, through: :tutor_subjects 
end
```

You would then assocatiate a tutor and subjects with:

```
<%= f.association :subjects, label_method: :name, as: :checkboxes, collection: Subject.all  %>
```